# OpenCV Python Android

Tags: android, python, opencv

Is it possible to code an Android application using the Python programming language with the OpenCV API?

I have coded an Android application using Python with the scripting layer for android (SL4A). Here is the website for SL4A:https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

However, using Python with the OpenCV API and the Android API is not something that I have done or read about when searching the Internet.

Python is so much more exciting than Java so I would rather use Python. It is more exciting because it is much more open-source and implicitly promotes more freedom.

Answer (score 2):

[According to here:](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24188/opencv-android-with-python/)

> there is sl4a / PythonForAndroid, unfortunately, it uses hardcoded java rmi invocations for anything os related. so - no opencv bindings there ;(
>   i guess, you'll have to learn java.
>   `-berak (Nov 20 '13)`

Also, although further dated, this [still open issue on github](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/75) leads me to believe that there is still no Python-Android OpenCV implementation.

> There is no camera implementation in Kivy right now. And we never said than opencv was available on python-for-android too.

But there is hope for the future:

> I have a plan of writing a recipe for it, not now, currently I am
>   quite overwhelmed by others ;-)
>   `- ParokshaX (Jul 25, 2014)`

**QUIK EDIT:**

Lol, there is a working implementation on the open issue, it just doesn't have a nice recipe:

> Here I attach the Eclipse project I have made to build libcv2.so for
>   Python on Android. It is a little bit messy because I really had a
>   headache working it out, and I'm short on time right now. Just import
>   it into Eclipse (I use ADT 22.0 and NDK r9c) and it should compile. I
>   took libopencv_java.so into the project so it shall be a dependency.
>   Also libpython2.7.so is a dependency too.  If anyone can make this
>   into a Python for Android recipe then that would be awesome.